# WebStorm code indentation issue

Tags: node.js, webstorm, serverless-framework

My WebStorm IDE has problems with indentation. It show notification at the top of the screen like:

> JSCS: Node interpreter file is not found

and

> ESLint: Please specify ESLint package

It shows when I tried to load the serverless framework project file. There is no problem when I write the NodeJS code directly.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try configuring javaScript language level for your project - seems that the parser doesn't recognize ES6 syntax in your code. In **Settings (Preferences) | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**, make sure to set **JavaScript language version** to `ECMAScript 6`.

ESLint and JSCS notifications have nothing to do with your issue - WebStorm has auto-enabled the corresponding integrations for you, likely because the corresponding configuration files/dependencies were found in your project. You can disable these integrations in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools**,  **ESLint** and **JSCS**, or set them up properly, by providing correct paths to Node.js interpreter, packages, etc.